# Azure kusto cluster table implement row level security with data columns based on which filtering would be done are across multiple tables?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, row-level-security

I am trying to implement row level security in Azure Kusto Cluster table but all the example which I see just works on a single table data. In my case to apply the filter, I need to join two tables. For e.g. I have tables X & Y, I need to apply row level security on table X but there is no column in table X which can help me apply filter, that column/data is there in table Y.
So, is this scenario possible in ADX Or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supported.
Here is a quick demo

```
.set-or-replace MyEventsTable <|
range EventID from 1 to 10 step 1
| extend EventTimestamp = ago(365d*rand())
| extend UserID = tolong(rand(3))
```

---

```
MyEventsTable
```

| EventID | EventTimestamp | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-29T12:52:38.8227264Z | 2 |
| 9 | 2021-09-11T12:53:42.8539446Z | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-10-09T05:29:14.3731005Z | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-11-09T09:59:12.1653628Z | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-11-15T08:10:06.9281365Z | 1 |
| 6 | 2022-01-02T09:46:46.9731912Z | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-03-09T07:44:31.2875361Z | 0 |
| 10 | 2022-03-14T01:10:23.1950573Z | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-04-28T08:03:51.4099464Z | 0 |
| 5 | 2022-05-04T05:08:15.941019Z | 2 |

```
.set-or-replace MyUsersTable <|
print UserEmail = pack_array("tic@microsoft.com", "tac@microsoft.com", current_principal_details().UserPrincipalName)
| mv-expand with_itemindex=UserID UserEmail to typeof(string)
| project-reorder UserID
```

---

```
MyUsersTable
```

| UserID | UserEmail |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | tic@microsoft.com |
| 1 | tac@microsoft.com |
| 2 | {manually redacted}@microsoft.com |

```
.create-or-alter function MyEventsTable_RLS(){
    MyEventsTable
    | where UserID == toscalar(MyUsersTable | where UserEmail == current_principal_details().UserPrincipalName | project UserID)
}
```

---

```
.alter table MyEventsTable policy row_level_security enable "MyEventsTable_RLS"
```

---

```
MyEventsTable
```

| EventID | EventTimestamp | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-29T12:52:38.8227264Z | 2 |
| 8 | 2021-10-09T05:29:14.3731005Z | 2 |
| 5 | 2022-05-04T05:08:15.941019Z | 2 |